# Action instance variable name matches which property of jsp tags(id or name)?

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2

This is a part of my Action class with getters and setters

```
private String userName; 
private String passWord;   

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

And here is my jsp code(only input tags):

```
<s:textfield name="userName" cssClass="input" id="userName" maxlength="64"/>
<s:password name="password" maxlength="15" cssClass="input" id="password" />
```

i just want to know :

Action class instance variables matches which property, id or name of the jsp tags such that my value automatically will be available to me on calling getters of corresponding variable. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form fields are mapped by the *name*. Ids are used in the javascript to locate the DOM elements by id. The `params` interceptor should be referenced to the action configuration to populate the action instance with the form input, it's a part of the `defaultStack` which your action config should reference explicitly or implicitly via the extending your package from `struts-default`.